# Lint not aborting build

Tags: android-studio, gradle, lint

I created new project (hello world) and did these steps:

1. added line `if (false) Log.d("AA", "BB")` (Lint is listing it as control-flow-issue warning)
2. added lines into build.gradle

   ```
   android {
       lintOptions {
           warningsAsErrors true
           checkAllWarnings true
           abortOnError true
       }
   }
   ```
3. added `gradle-aware make` with `:app:check` (or `:app:lint`) as first thing while bulding

Why am I able to build this project? Are there different types of warnings/lints? Because it actually does lint-fail on `GoogleAppIndexingWarning`. But not on simple things like above.

---

**Edit**

Looks like AndroidStudio lint is different than gradle lint. Different set of rules. Proved by running `./gradlew lint` with no issues.

I eventually want to stop commiting (pre-commit hook I guess) if **AndroidStudio** lint finds anything. Any solution/advice on that?